# Django forms: MultipleChoiceField does not select options from instance

Tags: django, django-forms, multiplechoicefield

I have a form from a model. Depending on "property_type" would be dynamically build a (or multiple) different field for "property_values". The result HTML form is right but the options for the multiple select field for "Property value" will not be selected from the instance.

My form is:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if 'instance' in kwargs:
            if self.instance.property_type == models.Property.RANGE:
                self.fields['property_values'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                    choices=(
                        ('lt', '<'),
                        ('eq', '='),
                        ('gt', '>')
                    )
                )
            self.fields['property_values'].label = 'Value'

    class Meta:
        model = models.Property
        fields = ['property_type', 'property_values']
        labels = {
            'property_type': 'Type',
        }
        widgets = {
            'property_type': forms.Select(),
        }
```

In the Database the field property_values is: `['eq', 'gt']`

[image]

Comment: You do set these three choices (options) in the constructor of your modelForm - and they are displayed. So what's the issue exactly? I didn't get it.

Comment: The select structure ist right. But the problem is that the values from the instance will not be selected at that select. There is no option:selected

Comment: Try again after adding a widget to your field: 
`self.fields['property_values'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                    choices=(
                        ('lt', '<'),
                        ('eq', '='),
                        ('gt', '>')
                    ),
                    widget=forms.SelectMultiple())`

Comment: It does not work. At the  MultipleChoiceField class definition is alredy `widget = SelectMultiple`

Comment: Mhhh... another idea is to initialize the choices in your Meta class. You can declare the `forms.SelectMultiple()` widget there (though it is the default widget) and add choices to the attrs of that widget. `widgets = {
            'property_type': forms.Select(), 'property_values' : forms.SelectMultiple(attrs=('choices' : (
                        ('lt', '<'),
                        ('eq', '='),
                        ('gt', '>')
                    ) ))
        }`

Comment: The question is that the field "property_values" must be dynamically set depending on "property_type". For each type may be a different type of field.

Comment: But in your code, property_values has these 3 choices fixed. Is your issue that (1) these 3 options are always there (static), though they're meant to be dynamic. Or (2) the selected items of property_values are not recognized as selected options in your http-POST?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151697/discussion-between-antonioromero-and-max-m).